# Add Multiple Rows Between 2 Values in Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3000+ rows of Data.  I want to find where Cell(x) = A and 
next Cell = B then add 5 blank rows between.

```
30.5
30.5
30.5
32.5
32.5
32.5
32.5
42.5
```

I have the below code almost works but Leaves one of "32.5s" Below the rows

```
Sub AddRow()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

    Col = "K"
    StartRow = 2
    BlankRows = 1

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, Col) = 32.5 And .Cells(R, Col).Offset(1, 0) = 42.5 Then
               .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
               .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
               .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
               .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
               .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. Quick fix: do the insertions this way:

```
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp  ' <-- R+1
```

That said, try to refactor your code, i.e. do these insertions in a little loop, and more importantly, *qualify* your ranges. The `With` clause is there to help you.

Comment: Schweet!!! A.S.H. thanks for your edit, answer and advice.  Still trying to figure it all out so I appreciate it.  Next up, I am going to try to get it to copy above cells in certain columns.  Stand by I guess :)